# Redirect on swipe with hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer

I need a help. I have a two links in ul.

```
<ul class="group switcher">
    <li><a href="/" id="next"><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="news-table.html" id="previous"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

When I swipe to right `#next`I want redirect to news-table.html. I use Hammer.js. Thank you!

Comment: do you use jQuery as well?

Comment: I can't use jquery mobile.

Comment: is this the answer you were after? if not, please let me know, if yes, please check as answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = { /* your options*/};

$('#next').hammer(options).bind("swiperight", function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(window).location.replace(href);
});
```

only answered by reading the documentation. might need some adjustments in your code...

Comment: Can I ask you, what should be in Options? Thank you

Comment: i don't know hammerjs, never worked with it. but it seems that you don't even have to pass the options-object. So `$('#next').hammer().bind(...)` should work already. in the options-object you simply pass hammerjs-options if needed.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm tested this a moment ago. But still show this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hammer is not a function at swipe-button.js:2. I added a jquery.hammer.js plugin and still not working. Thanks!